Torque causing translational motion
I don't understand how a force acting perpendicular to a free to move rigid rod on a frictionless surface cause rotational and translaton motion at the same time while there are no forces acting towards the COM.

The COM is a point. How can a direction be orthogonal to a point? Please, improve your question. I'm voting to close it

Per Newton’s 2nd law the translational acceleration of a rigid body is
$$a=\frac{F_{net}}{m}$$
Where $F_{net}$ is the net force of all the forces acting on the body, regardless of the point of application, which may or may not include a force whose direction is through the center of mass (COM).
The result is all points on the rigid body, including at point at the location of the COM, undergo this same translational acceleration. This is in addition to any rotational acceleration due to a net torque that may also act on the body.
What is unique about the center of mass is we can, for a rigid body, consider all the mass located at this point when considering the translational motion of the rigid body.
Hope this helps.

Thanks for the explanation!

@ArisPan You are welcome
